# How to Override forceInset prop for <SafeAreaView> in React navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, tabbar

I have created a bottom tab bar using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html) which I need to animate/collapse on scroll. However when user scrolls, the safe area view is not animated and remains at the bottom (I want it to hide as well when the bottom tab bar hides). In order to fix that, I did this:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }} forceInset={{ bottom: 'never' }}>
    <AppContainer />
</SafeAreaView>
```

and tried to set the bottom safearea view on my custom tab bar so that when I animate it, the entire nav bar (including the safe area view is animated)

```
const MainBottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
    firstTab: { screen: FirstScreen },
    secondTab: { screen: SecondScreen },
    thirdTab: { screen: ThirdScreen },
},
{
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      return {
        tabBarComponent: props => ( <MyCustomNavBar {...props} /> ),
        tabBarOptions: { safeAreaInset: { bottom: 'always' } },
      };
    },
  }
);
```

I tried to put `tabBarOptions` in different places but none of them works. One thing I found out was if I remove the custom tab bar and just use the default tab bar, then it works. Is there a way to override forceInset on a custom tab bar?